# Deployment Issue - Application not accessible on home network

Tags: dns, cloudflare, onrender

I have deployed my application on OnRender, purchased a domain, and set up Cloudflare for DNS management. The application works fine on external networks, but I'm facing an issue when trying to access it from my home network.

Here are the details of my setup:

- I can access other websites from my home network without any problems.
- The application is deployed on OnRender, and the domain is configured on Cloudflare.
- Port forwarding is set up on my home router for the application's port.
- I have checked the DNS settings on my home router, and they seem to be correct.

Despite these efforts, I am unable to access the application when connected to my home router.
I see this when go to Hobyloc.com
[image]

I would appreciate any insights or troubleshooting steps to identify and resolve this issue. Has anyone faced a similar problem, and what steps can I take to debug and fix the problem?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest you to verify if all DNS servers response with the same IP address of your domain, it should be called from home network(and you can also try from the other).

```bash
nslookup your.domain
nslookup your.domain 8.8.8.8
nslookup your.domain 1.1.1.1
```

If all the results gives you the same IP address, so the DNS is fine.

Second possible thing, as you wrote `Port forwarding is set up on my home router for the application's port.` so you are trying to access your local network resource using your external IP address(your public IP returned by DNS server) from the local network, the issue might be [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning) and if your route doesn't support it you can't do much about it, you just need better router. One workaround for this would be using some external proxy, as you already using Cloudflare you can look into their [Proxied records](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/reference/proxied-dns-records/#proxied-records) as everything will be behind proxy everything should work fine and it will give more additional DDOS Protection.